# Is there a way to directly iterate a series through a dict in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out the best way to iterate a series through a dictionary in pandas. Here is my MRE:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])

d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

what I want to do is create s2 such that

```
s2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
```

by processing s1 through d. So far, the best way I can think of is

```
s2 = pd.Series([d[item] for item in list(s1)])
```

I am aware of the option to do

```
s2 = pd.Series(d.values())
```

but the actual problem I am trying to solve would require passing the series through a dictionary.

Comment: In the statement, `s2 = pd.Series(d.values())`, you are already passing the series through the dictionary, `d`...what's the problem then?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that definition doesn't pass anything through the dictionary, it just takes the list of dictionary values and converts it into a series. Not the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s1 = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
s2 = s1.map(d)
```

output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `replace`

```
s2 = s1.replace(d)
s2
Out[17]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```